# How can I change the callback of a uielement using get()?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, callback, matlab-guide, uielement

**Some background**

I've created a GUI using a combination of a GUIDE built Figure and procedurally placed checkboxes that are added at runtime.  The checkboxes are in a matrix where the number of rows and columns is determined at runtime.  To keep track of each checkbox I use a tag convention like `cb_r1_c1` or `cb_r7_c10` which indicates the location in the matrix.

I've created a function `foo_cb_callback()` which examines the hObject information passed to it to determine the tag of the checkbox that was just clicked.  Using this information (row and col of the checkbox) this function knows what to do next.  I find this to be a much cleaner and safer way to handle the callbacks of an unknown amount of checkboxes.  So far this strategy is working great. There is only one problem.

**The Problem**

I'm having trouble changing the callback property of my procedurally added checkboxes to properly call my `foo_cb_callback()` function.

When you examine an existing checkbox with an existing call back using `get(objhandles.cb_r1_c1,'callback')`

the returned variable is of class "function_handle" and prints a string of text to the screen

```
@(hObject,eventdata)testfuig('checkbox1_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))
```

I would like to change this to

```
@(hObject,eventdata)testfuig('foo_cb_callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))
```

**What I Tried First**

My first attempt was something like this.

```
callbackstr = '@(hObject,eventdata)testfuig(''foo_cb_callback'',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))';
set(objhandles.cb_r1_c1,'callback',callbackstr);
```

But this doesn't work since it is just a string and not a function_handle classed object.  It seems like there should be some way to take a string or cell array and convert it to a function_handle class.  This would be the most ideal situation since I could easily control the callback of any uielement easily.

**What I Tried Next**

Since I was already constructing the checkboxes using the 'uicontrol()' function I tried to add the callback at the time of creation.

```
tagstr = 'cb_r1_c1';
uicontrol(objhandles.mainfig, 'Style','checkbox','Tag',tagstr,'callback', 'foo_cb_callback(''hObject''));
```

This created the checkbox and indeed had `foo_cb_callback(hObject)` in the callback property, but when the checkbox is clicked I get an error `??? Undefined function or variable 'hObject'.`

**So I Gave Up, and Worked Around It**

I found two non-ideal solutions to work around this issue.  The first was to create a non visible checkbox in GUIDE with tag `cb_hidden`.  Then I was able to use the following code.

```
callback = get(objhandles.cb_hidden, 'callback');
set(objhandles.cb_r1_c1,'callback',callback);
```

This correctly set the callback of `cb_r1_c1` to the same callback as `cb_hidden`.  In this way I was able to redirect all checkbox callbacks to this dummy checkbox, and from there call `foo_cb_callback(hObject)`.

However, this solution is non ideal because it requires a hidden checkbox somewhere in the GUI.

**Another Work Around**

Since I was creating unique tags at runtime for each checkbox, I decided to write the tag directly into the callback string.

```
tagstr = 'cb_r1_c1';
uicontrol(objhandles.mainfig, 'Style','checkbox','Tag',tagstr,'callback', 'foo_cb_callback(''' tagstr  '''));
```

This sets the callback to `foo_cb_callback('cb_r1_c1')`  which correctly calls `foo_cb_callback()` and passes the string `'cb_r1_c1'`.  The first few lines of `foo_cb_callback()` look like this

```
function foo_cb_callback(tag)
global gdata
hObject = gdata.objhandles.(tag);
```

From there I can do pretty much anything I would have been able to do using an ideal solution.  **However, this solution is still not ideal**, since I am unable to pass in variables (other than non changing strings).  Also, I would really like to know the proper way to do this, I'm sure I will find a use for it someday.

Comment: +1 for an excellent explanation of your problem!

Comment: here's a link to the relevant documentation: [Write Code for Callbacks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_guis/f16-999606.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does something simple like this not work?

```
function myCallback(src, event)
    disp('myCallback called');
end


set(hObject, 'callback', @myCallback);
```

Comment: This worked!  But the area I call set() is not in the same mfile so I had to pass in an argument all the way from the main figure m file.

Answer (score 1):

What you tried first,

```
callbackstr = '@(hObject,eventdata)testfuig(''foo_cb_callback'',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))';
set(objhandles.cb_r1_c1,'callback',callbackstr);
```

was very close. You just don't need to set a string, but rather a function handle (to an anonymous function in your case):

```
callbackFun = @(hObject,eventdata)testfuig('foo_cb_callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject));
set(objhandles.cb_r1_c1,'callback',callbackFun);
```

Also, should it really say `testfuig`?

Comment: It looks like I need to go read up on function handles and anonymous functions.  testfuig was probably the name I quickly typed into guide to make a quick figure to show my problem on the web (my real code is no on this machine).